# Can't deploy image from jenkins to docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, gradle

I'm trying to deploy an image to docker from jenkins which is also running from docker.
From the jenkins I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
    Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'docker'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:98)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:71)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline/build/docker"): error=13, Permission denied
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    ... 8 more
```

Here's the relevant jenkins file part

```
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            sh './gradlew docker dockerRun --stacktrace'
        }
    }
```

and also part of the gradle script responsible for the deployment

```
docker {
    name "registry/spring-boot-api-example:1.1"
    files "build/libs/${bootJar.archiveFileName.get()}"
    buildArgs([JAR_FILE: bootJar.archiveFileName.get()])
}
```

and also docker-comose file which contains jenkins container configuration

```
jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:2.235.1-lts-centos7
    privileged: true
    hostname: jenkins
    user: root
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '50000:50000'
    container_name: jenkins
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

Comment: are you certain docker is available within the jenkins build server?

Comment: Actually when I connect to the container using bash, and try to execute the same command by hand I get an error that docker command isn't available, but how do I enable it?

Comment: reason I ask is we had something similar. We were running a jenkins container in a container that had docker. Docker wasn't available within the jenkins container. I believe you can use "docker in docker" to have the two working together. It took me a day or two to realise the `whoami` user was `jenkins` in the container but outside the container was not. This is probably enough to identify if you have the same problem